# Word Permutation Generator

Tags: c

I found several examples of what I was looking to do, but none worked quite exactly how I wanted, of course.

I'm trying to modify the following program to display all possible combinations of a string of words. So, for example:

```
*str = "one two"; // would be:
one two
two one

*str = "one two three"; // would be:
one two three
one three two

two one three
two three one

three one two
three two one
```

etc..

Here is what I am working with, which produces duplicates as well, which I do not want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* Function to print permutations of string
   This function takes three parameters:
   1. String
   2. Starting index of the string
   3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
   int i;
   if (l == r)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
       for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
       {
          swap((a+l), (a+i));
          permute(a, l+1, r);
          swap((a+l), (a+i)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */    
int main()
{
    char str[] = "one two three";
    int n = strlen(str);
    permute(str, 0, n-1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a read of `std::next_permutation` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: The [tag:c++] tag appears to have no place in this question.

Comment: Are you asking for a c or a c++ solution? They will likely be very different.

Comment: Do you want to permute words or characters? Right now you are not considering the words.

Comment: This program seems correct, but it makes permutation of the characters. If you want to make permutations of words, you just have to modify it to work on an array of words.

Comment: Seems like the example has some typos, e.g. `two three two` doesn't seem right.

Comment: Corrected. Yes, I was hoping for a C solution, not C++. It works with letters, but I do not know how to make it work words only.

Comment: Since the string has three words, I would create a string with three letters, e.g. `"abc"`. Then permute the letters. When it comes time to print, substitute the words for the letters. For example, print "one" instead of "a", etc.

Comment: @user3386109 : you have made a simple problem over-complicated.  Split the string at the space-delimiters (using strtok() for example) and simply generate permutations of the _pointers_ to each word.

Comment: _Yes, I was hoping for a C solution_: hmm, so why did you use the C++ tag in first place?

Comment: @Clifford Your solution runs into problems when starting with a string that contains duplicates, like `"one two one three"`.

Comment: @user3386109 : They are distinct strings - the OP is not clear about what is required.  If that is the requirement then he first has to generate the _set of unique words_.  I am not sure how your suggestion solves the problem of duplication either - the association of letter to locations in the string is hard to implement or strings of an arbitrary number of words.

Comment: Dumping [somone else's code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) verbatim and without attribution then asking how to adapt it to solve a different (and ambiguously defined) problem does not make for a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
char str[] = "one two three";
```

try starting with

```
char *strs[3];
strs[0] = "one";
strs[1] = "two";
strs[2] = "three";
```

And then modify your existing algorithm to work with that.